# (Swift - OOP) How to segue a class instantiated in Swift (VC1) to Objective C (VC2) to Swift (VC3)

Tags: objective-c, swift, oop, segue

I'm just a beginner in swift and I'm trying to perform an OOP style by creating a class, then setting its properties to:

```
@objc class Person: NSObject{

var firstName: String = ""

public func getFirstName() ->String
{
    return firstName
}

public func setFirstName(name: String)
{
    firstname = name
}}
```

I used a sidebar menu from AppCoda, its coding is in objective-c. Somehow, I was able to make it work. However now, I created a login swift controller (VC1) and I want to pass the data I've got from php, store it in the instantiated class (Person), then pass Person to that objective C class (VC2), then use Person from VC2 to another controller swift I created, (VC3). Can you provide a sample code for passing of classes from swift to objective c to another swift?

Thank you!

What I've tried:

VC1:
    //segue part

```
var personClass = Person()
personClass.setFirstName(name: "Sample")
let DestinationViewController:LetsTry = segue.destination as! LetsTry
DestinationViewController.personClass = personClass
```

VC2: (I really don't know how to objective-c, but some guides from other posts which I don't understand that much)

//header file of objective-c

```
@interface LetsTry : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) id firstName;
- (void) someMethod;
@end
```

VC3:

//didload

```
var personClass = Person()
personClass = LetsTry() as! Person

textbox1.text = personClass.getFirstName()
```

Then it throws me you cannot assign "Person" to type "Lets Try"

Comment: Please show what you have tried, we aren't going to do your work for you.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry edited

Comment: OK, just to summarize. You have a `UIViewController`, your LoginViewController. In that ViewController you create a `Person` object. Then you have your `LetsTry` class? Is that supposed to be your VC2 which you would like to pass your `Person` to? (because in your code it seems to be just a subclass of a "normal" `NSObject` and not a `UIViewController`). And finally, how is `VC3` defined? Is that a `UIViewController`? (it seems so)

Comment: Hello @pbodsk, yes. My VC1 is the logincontroller, the class 'Person' is instantiated and populated in that class. I want to pass that class to an objective-c class (VC2) then, I want VC2 to pass it to VC3, named 'homecontroller', which is swift. Using segue or other solutions you may suggest :D

Comment: Right now, I made the class 'Person', its properties and methods, to static so that it could be accessed by VC3, But I think it wouldn't be OOP if it's static.

Comment: Because I used a template from AppCoda, VC3, which is a navigation controller (named homecontroller), is opened by that VC2, an objective-c class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do here, and therefore this answer may be wrong.

But...as I read it, you have two `UIViewController`s, one called `LoginViewController` and another called `HomeController`, in between those you have your `LetsTry` class, which is an ObjC class, and now you would like your `Person` object to be passed from `LoginViewController` to `HomeController` by adding it as a property to your `LetsTry` class.

To do that, you'd add your `Person` as a property on `LetsTry` like so:

```
#import "Person.h" <-- don't quote me on this one, maybe it isn't needed

@interface LetsTry : NSObject
    @property (strong, nonatomic) id firstName;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) Person *person;
    - (void) someMethod;
@end
```

Next, your segue should go from `LoginViewController` to `HomeController`, meaning that the `destination` of your `segue` should be an instance of `HomeController`. Furthermore, `HomeController` should have an instance of `LetsTry` like so:

```
var letsTry: LetsTry?
```

Now we are ready to start tying things together.

First you need to add your `Person` to your `LetsTry` in the segue, so instead of this (which isn't working at all :))

```
var personClass = Person()
personClass.setFirstName(name: "Sample")
let DestinationViewController:LetsTry = segue.destination as! LetsTry
DestinationViewController.personClass = personClass
```

You'd do something like:

```
var personClass = Person()
personClass.setFirstName(name: "Sample")
var letsTry = LetsTry()
letsTry.person = person

if let destinationViewController: HomeController = segue.destination as? HomeController {
    destinationViewController.letsTry = letsTry
}
```

And finally, in your `HomeController` instead of:

```
var personClass = Person()
personClass = LetsTry() as! Person

textbox1.text = personClass.getFirstName()
```

You'd do:

```
if let letsTry = letsTry {
    textbox1.text = letsTry.person.getFirstName()
}
```

### Counter question :)

When you look at the above, you might start to wonder whether you need the `LetsTry` class at all. You could just use the `Person` class in your `HomeController`. But you probably have a reason for doing what you are doing.

### Things to consider

Your `Person` class seems a bit "Java-esque", or C# maybe. You don't need the `get` and `set` methods, you can just use the var straight away. That means that you can write your `Person` like this:

```
@objc class Person: NSObject{
    var firstName: String = ""
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var person = Person()
var person.firstName = "Peter"

print(person.firstName) //gives me "Peter"
```

Hope this helps you in any way. You might want to read up on segues, try having a look at the tutorials at http://raywenderlich.com for instance

Comment: Hello @pbodsk, btw class 'Person' is an another swift file (not controller, just class). Now, my problem is if i put the code you suggested "@interface LetsTry : NSObject ....." in the objective-c class with .h extension, it couldn't find the class 'Person'. On the other hand, if I put it in the objective-c class with .m extension, it can now access the class 'Person' from swift however, my swift controllers  couldn't find the 'LetsTry' class from that objective-c class with .m extension. Any solutions?

Comment: oh, adding @class Person; on top of the implementation worked, will now try your suggestion.

Comment: Hello, so there's now a buildtime error with code: 

var personClass = Person()
personClass.setFirstName(name: "Sample")
var letsTry = LetsTry()
letsTry.person = person

It says: 
-"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LetsTry", referenced from:
-linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I don't have any answers to that one sorry :( But from the top of my mind. Have you added a "bridging header" file to your project? Have a look at this document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html especially the section "To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same target"

Comment: oh I had to add @implementation at the .m file

Comment: Anyways thank you!! With a few tweaks, it seemed that I only needed to add '@class Person' inside the file 'SWRevealViewController.h' (VC2), under the class 'SWRevealViewController' and add a property of person, '@property (strong, nonatomic) Person *person' along SWRevealViewController class' properties. Problem solved!

Comment: I can now use the class 'Person' in VC3 from that objective-c VC2 (that was passed by VC1) by e.g. 'revealViewController().person.firstName', thank you again sir! Will be looking forward for the tutorials in your website!